# CodeIgniter - How to redirect into non WWW URL with sessions

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, redirect, no-www

In my CodeIgniter project, when I try to redirect from one controller to some other controller/function, An extra "WWW" comes just in front of the URL. With that WWW-URL, I can't access my old session information created in the non-WWW site.

my redirect code is below.

```
public function test()
{
    $this->load->helper('url');
    redirect('/Cat/view');
}
```

the URL looks like below

```
http://app.mysite.com/login                   << where I set session info
http://www.app.mysite.com/index.php/Cat/View  << After redirect
```

how can redirect from non-www site to non-www site safely in CodeIgnitor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the issue fixed by modifying my **.htaccess** file to rewrite the URL without **WWW** if it is there.

The first part of the below code is to remove **"WWW"** and the second part is to remove **"index.php"** from the URL

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```